# Delete cells with #NA using if statement in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete #NA within this code, I know you suppose to a if statement but I don't know where and how i should write it within my code

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim CopyColumns() As Variant
CopyColumns = Array("B", "E", "H", "K", "N")
Dim Col As Variant


  Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ba pricing")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loader")

        For Each Col In CopyColumns

          lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

          lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

          wsCopy.Range(Col & "30:" & Col & lCopyLastRow).Copy
          wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues



         Next Col


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i could not understand the requirement clearly, i assumed #NA is to be deleted from destination only. I would prefer to do the deletion  after completion of copy paste task only.

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim CopyColumns() As Variant
CopyColumns = Array("B", "E", "H", "K", "N")
Dim Col As Variant

Dim FinalStartRow As Long
Dim FinalEndRow As Long
Dim Cel As Range

Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ba pricing")
Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loader")

FinalStartRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
FinalEndRow = 0

        For Each Col In CopyColumns
          lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
          lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
          wsCopy.Range(Col & "30:" & Col & lCopyLastRow).Copy
          wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          FinalEndRow = FinalEndRow + lCopyLastRow - 30 + 1
         Next Col


    For Each Cel In wsDest.Range("C" & FinalStartRow & ":C" & FinalEndRow).Cells
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cel) Then
        Cel.Delete xlShiftUp   ' if required to delete cell
        'Cel.ClearContents     ' if required to delete contents only
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit: If You want to skip the copying the whole column if it contains #N/A then simply modify your code  Like this

```
For Each Col In CopyColumns
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    If wsCopy.Range(Col & "30:" & Col & lCopyLastRow).Find("#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
    wsCopy.Range(Col & "30:" & Col & lCopyLastRow).Copy
    wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
 Next Col
```

Edit2: added to copy 2nd Set of columns into Column H

```
Dim CopyRng As Range, CopyRng2 As Range

        For Each Col In CopyColumns
          lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
          lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
          Set CopyRng = wsCopy.Range(Col & "30:" & Col & lCopyLastRow)
          'Since the 2nd set of columns specified is just at the right of columns specified in the 1st set
          Set CopyRng2 = wsCopy.Range(CopyRng(1, 1).Offset(0, 1), CopyRng(CopyRng.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, 1))

            If CopyRng.Find("#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
            CopyRng.Copy
            wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            CopyRng2.Copy
            wsDest.Range("H" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
         Next Col
```

Comment: well the macro copy values from column ("B", "E", "H", "K", "N"). it varies because sometime all 5 columns will have data and sometime it will not, depends on the day. So some days only 2/5 or 3/5 columns will get filled. so those blank columns will have N/A when copy over – thanh1211 1 hour ago   @ ahmed au

Comment: @thanh1211 answer Added with Edit to skip the copying the whole column if it contains #N/A within.

Comment: thank you! it works!. I have one more question...what if I have data from "wsCopy" worksheet in  array ("C", "F", "I", "L", "O"). and I want to copy this data into column H in "wsDest" worksheet. how do i nest that into the code I have now?

Comment: sorry im new to VBA , what If I want to add a code to the loop that basically does the same thing except this time copy data in one single cell instead of multiple rows in the "wsCopy"  and paste it down to the last row in the the "wsDest"  in column I this time.

Comment: Could not quite understand your latest comment. is it regarding last edit (if solution in last edit worked as intended) ?

Comment: apology should've been clearer, but no its regarding a different code

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to delete #N/A errors after copying the values from the formulas in a set of columns, why not simply skip copying the #N/A errors to begin with?

```
Sub valueOnlyCopy()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim copyColumns As Variant, col As Variant
    Dim valRng As Range, wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet

    copyColumns = Array("B", "E", "H", "K", "N")
    Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ba pricing")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loader")

    For Each col In copyColumns

        With wsCopy
            With .Range(.Cells(30, col), .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp))
                Set valRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers + xlTextValues + xlLogical)
            End With
        End With

        With wsDest
            For a = 1 To valRng.Areas.Count
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(valRng.Areas(a).Rows.Count, 1) = _
                  valRng.Areas(a).Value
            Next a
        End With

    Next col

End Sub
```

Comment: well the macro copy values from column ("B", "E", "H", "K", "N"). it varies because sometime all 5 columns will have data and sometime it will not, depends on the day. So some days only 2/5 or 3/5 columns will get filled. so those blank columns will have N/A when copy over